# How does gtol parameter work in scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a Gaussian model onto gaussian distributed data (x,y) , using scipy's curve_fit. I am trying to tweak the parameters of the fitting, in order to get better fitting. I saw that curve_fit calls scipy.optimize.least_sq with the method LM (Levenberg-Marquardt method). It seems to me that it constructs a function that evaluates the least square criterion at each data point. In my example, I have 8 data points. In my comprehension and according to scipy's documentation gtol is "Orthogonality desired between the function vector and the columns of the Jacobian."

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(parametrized_gaussian, patch_indexes * pixel_size, sub_sig,
                                    p0=p0, jac=gaussian_derivative_wrt_param, maxfev=max_fev, gtol=1e-11, ftol=1e-11, xtol=1e-11)
```

parametrized_gaussian is simply :

```
def parametrized_gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma) :

    res = a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

    return res.astype('float64')
```

and gaussian_derivative_wrt_param is

```
def gaussian_derivative_wrt_param(x, a, x0, sigma):
   
 return np.array([parametrized_gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma) / a,
                  2 * (x - x0) / (sigma ** 2) * parametrized_gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma),
                  (x - x0) ** 2 / (sigma ** 3) * parametrized_gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma)]). swapaxes(0, -1).astype('float64')
```

I wanted to check that the value of the jacobian at the resulting optimal parameters. I do not understand the values that I get. When curve_fit calls leastsq, it then uses :

```
        retval = _minpack._lmder(func, Dfun, x0, args, full_output,
                             col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev,
                             factor, diag)
```

I print Dfun(retval[0]), because retval[0] is the values of optimal parameters. This is what I get.
0.18634,-6175.62246,5660.31995

0.50737, -10685.47212, 6223.84575

0.88394, -7937.93400, 1971.45501

0.98540, 3054.98273, 261.93803

0.70291, 10670.53623, 4479.93075

0.32083, 8746.05579, 6594.01140

0.09370, 3686.25245, 4010.79420

0.01751, 900.40686, 1280.50557

How does this respect gtol ??

[Results for Dfun(optimal parameters on the grid of 8 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG9GU.png)

That is why I think I do not understand how gtol works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From scipy/optimize/minpack/lmder.f, we find a more detailed description

```
c       gtol is a nonnegative input variable. termination
c         occurs when the cosine of the angle between fvec and
c         any column of the jacobian is at most gtol in absolute
c         value. therefore, gtol measures the orthogonality
c         desired between the function vector and the columns
c         of the jacobian.
```

This just means that if `gtol=0`, then `f(x_optimal)` and columns of the jacobian are perpendicular on convergence. If this is the case, then `f'(x_optimal).T @ f(x_optimal)` is a zero matrix. Since this product is used as part of the iteration, it makes sense to stop when this is `0`, because no more progress can made.